# no validation style for empty fields

Tags: html, css, forms, validation

How to set a validation style for required fields without affecting empty fields?

Thank you in advance!

```
Code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyOJoN?editors=1100
```

Comment: Add required  in input field and add css as    input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
} check the same in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEjEmQ

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
input[required] {
    // styles goes here
}
```

This only affects fields with the **required** attribute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
:required:not(empty) {
  background: red;
}
```